# PHP "include" fails (redux)

Tags: php, include

Sorry for another "php include" chapter but searching on that gives some 90,000 entries and I feel like I've read 1/2 of 'em.

I'm resurrecting a web page I wrote some 9 years ago on Win 2000 Pro.  Since then I've easily ported it to Ubuntu 10.0, Windows 7 and published it online through 2 different hosting sites.  Now I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot get the php "include" command to work.  The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Menu movietime.php</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);?>

<body background="wood.gif">
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenn" value="hide & ">
<hidden name="hidden" value="well hid">
</form>

<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'menu.php';
?>

<h1 align="center"><strong>Movie Database</strong></h1>
<h2 align="center"><strong>Main Menu  </strong></h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
<?php
echo '<h3 align="center"><strong>'.$status.'</strong></h3>';
?>
```

The problem here is that the include for 'menu.php' never happens so the links to the rest of the application don't appear.  The code for menu.php is:

```
<div align="center">
<font size="2">
<a href="../">Home Page</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="create.php">Create Movie Table</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="drop.php">Delete Movie Table </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="list_radio.php">List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="add.php">Add Movie</a>
<a href="delete.php">Delete Movie</a></font>
</div>
```

The follow-on php statement to display the $status always works.  I'd like to show you the resultant page but I don't have enough points to do so ( I think ... first time on here ).

Things I have tried are:

- ctrl-u on Firefox shows the source.  The source displayed by ctrl-u
  is no different than the original code.
- I set up a php_errors.log file in /var/log and pointed to it within
  php.ini.  Nothing ever goes into it.  Permissions are 755.  I even
  misspelled "include" and still no errors.
- Substituted php.ini_development for php.ini and still no go.
  (error_reporting and display_errors were enabled in both).
- I tail -f the Apache access.log in one xterm window and tail -f
  the error.log in another. The only time I see output in error.log is when
  I shutdown/startup Apache.  The only time I see output in access.log
  is when I reload the page.  It shows a GET for movietime.php and a
  GET for wood.gif and that's it.
- Tried substituting a full directory reference for "dirname(**FILE**)" in the include statement ... nogo.

Don't know what else to do at this point.  I'm running Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9

I look forward to any and all suggestions / insights.

--thanks
  --Gary

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);?>` and `<?php
include (dirname(__FILE__).'/menu.php');
?>`

Comment: `dirname()` doesn't return a trailing slash, so you're producing `/foo/barmenu.php`, instead of `/foo/bar/menu.php`. And if you're seeing the PHP code in your browser's view source, then you're **NOT** executing the php code at all. the script is being sent out as a plain text.

Comment: I added the 'ini_set' in there and corrected the missing '/' in front of menu.php and still see nothing.

Comment: I see the 'echo $status' code in the browsers view source and I also see that piece of PHP get executed and displayed on my page.  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your urls have an absolute path, like:
/path/file.php 
not
path/file.php

Comment: if include() doesn't work, require() isn't going to work either.